# How can I check if my node allows incoming connections?

Tags: monerod, monerod-commands

So I finally setup my own Monero full node, and forwarded the port 18080 to my internal host.

How can I check in the `monerod` log output that the node allows incoming connections?

How long does it take to be listed in the Monero nodes list? https://monerohash.com/nodes-distribution.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check with command `print_cn` in monero daemon. If it shows connections with prefix IN (for Incoming), you are running succesfully a node which handles incomming conections

Answer (score 4):

You can type the command `status` in monerod. This will show something like the following, in green:

> Height: 1226605/1226605 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash
>   51.39 MH/s, v4, up to date, 8+6 connections

The first number in the `8+6 connections` part refers to the number of outgoing connections. The second number refers to the number of incoming connections.

If you see a positive number after the plus (+) sign, then your node is allowing incoming connections. In the example above, 6 incoming users are connected to my node. If it showed `8+0` instead, I would have no incoming connections on my node and it is probably not set up properly to allow incoming connections.